# React-router-v6 access a url parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**How can i access url parameter in my react component ?**

App.js

```
<Route path="/question/:id" element={<QuestionView />} />
```

QuestionView.js

```
class QuestionView extends React.Component {     
    render() {
          const { questions, users } = this.props;
          const {id} = ???
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Issue

In react-router-dom v6 the `Route` components no longer have route props (`history`, `location`, and `match`), and the current solution is to use the React hooks "versions" of these to use within the components being rendered. React hooks can't be used in class components though.

To access the match params with a class component you must either convert to a function component, or roll your own custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component to inject the "route props" like the `withRouter` HOC from `react-router-dom` v5.x did.

## Solution

I won't cover converting a class component to function component. Here's an example custom `withRouter` HOC:

```
const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const params = useParams();
  // etc... other react-router-dom v6 hooks

  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      params={params}
      // etc...
    />
  );
};
```

And decorate the component with the new HOC.

```
export default withRouter(Post);
```

This will inject a `params` prop for the class component.

```
this.props.params.id
```

Answer (score 10):

### HOC `withRouter` TypeScript version with generic Params

#### withRouter.tsx

```typescript
import { ComponentType } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface WithRouterProps<T = ReturnType<typeof useParams>> {
  history: {
    back: () => void;
    goBack: () => void;
    location: ReturnType<typeof useLocation>;
    push: (url: string, state?: any) => void;
  }
  location: ReturnType<typeof useLocation>;
  match: {
    params: T;
  };
  navigate: ReturnType<typeof useNavigate>;
}

export const withRouter = <P extends object>(Component: ComponentType<P>) => {
  return (props: Omit<P, keyof WithRouterProps>) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const match = { params: useParams() };
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const history = {
      back: () => navigate(-1),
      goBack: () => navigate(-1),
      location,
      push: (url: string, state?: any) => navigate(url, { state }),
      replace: (url: string, state?: any) => navigate(url, {
        replace: true,
        state
      })
    };

    return (
      <Component
        history={history}
        location={location}
        match={match}
        navigate={navigate}
        {...props as P}
      />
    );
  };
};
```

#### MyClass.tsx

```typescript
import { Component } from 'react';

import { withRouter, WithRouterProps } from './withRouter';

interface Params {
  id: string;
}

type Props = WithRouterProps<Params>;

class MyClass extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    console.log(match.params.id); // with autocomplete
    return <div>MyClass</div>;
  }
}

export default withRouter(MyClass);
```

Comment: Your solution is really noisy, I hope this is not the simplest approach when using TypeScript and React Class Component. But thank you so much for showing it, it works like a charm.

Comment: His solution is noisy, because the newer versions of React try to do everything to force the developers to use functional components. It is really sad.

Comment: Notice how hey force you to wrap a class component into a functional component.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use a class, then you will need to wrap it with the `withRouter`. I provide an example below:

This is my class for the movie form:

```
class MovieForm extends Form {

    state = {
        data: {
            title: "",
            genreId: "",
            numberInStock: "",
            dailyRentalRate: ""
        },
        genres: [],
        errors: {}
    };

    schema = {
        _id: Joi.string(),
        title: Joi.string()
            .required()
            .label("Title"),
        genreId: Joi.string()
            .required()
            .label("Genre"),
        numberInStock: Joi.number()
            .required()
            .min(0)
            .max(100)
            .label("Number in Stock"),
        dailyRentalRate: Joi.number()
            .required()
            .min(0)
            .max(10)
            .label("Daily Rental Rate")
    };




    componentDidMount() {

        const genres = getGenres();
        this.setState({ genres });

        // const movieId = this.props.match.params.id;
        const movieId = this.props.params.id;
        if (movieId === "new") return;

        const movie = getMovie(movieId);
        if (!movie) return this.props.history.replace("/not-found");

        this.setState({ data: this.mapToViewModel(movie) });
    }

    mapToViewModel(movie) {
        return {
            _id: movie._id,
            title: movie.title,
            genreId: movie.genre._id,
            numberInStock: movie.numberInStock,
            dailyRentalRate: movie.dailyRentalRate
        };
    }


    doSubmit = () => {
        saveMovie(this.state.data);
        this.props.navigate("/movies");
    };



    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Movie Form</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    {this.renderInput("title", "Title")}
                    {this.renderSelect("genreId", "Genre", this.state.genres)}
                    {this.renderInput("numberInStock", "Number in Stock", "number")}
                    {this.renderInput("dailyRentalRate", "Rate")}
                    {this.renderButton("Save")}
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I write a wrapper outside of the class:

```
const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
    const params = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
        <WrappedComponent
            {...props}
            params={params}
            navigate={navigate}
        />
    );
};
```

Now, at the end of the file I will export it like below:

```
export default withRouter(MovieForm);
```

Insdie the `withRouter`, I get all the functions that I will use later inside the class:

```
const params = useParams();
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code example I'm using in my project to get the id from the URL:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Button} from 'antd'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

const DeleteUser = () => {

    const {id} = useParams()
const handleDelete = async () => {
        // handle delete function
    }


  return (
    <Button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete User</Button>
  )
}

export default DeleteUser
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript version

withRouter.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    useLocation,
    useNavigate,
    useParams,
    NavigateFunction,
    Params,
    Location,
} from 'react-router-dom';

export interface RouterProps {
    router: {
        navigate: NavigateFunction;
        readonly params: Params<string>;
        location: Location;
    }
}

function withRouter(Component: React.ComponentType<RouterProps>) {
    const ComponentWithRouterProp: React.FC = () => {
        const location = useLocation();
        const navigate = useNavigate();
        const params = useParams();

        return (
            <Component
                router={{ location, navigate, params }}
            />
        );
    };

    return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

export default withRouter;
```

MyComponent.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { RootState } from '@@/redux/store';
import {
    addSettings,
    updateSettings,
} from '@@/redux/mySlice';
import withRouter, { RouterProps } from '@@/withRouter';

const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({
    myStore: state.variation.myStore,
});

const mapDispatch = {
    addSettings,
    updateSettings,
};

type IProps = ReturnType<typeof mapState> & typeof mapDispatch & RouterProps;

class MyComponent extends React.Component<IProps> {
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    onNavigateHome = () => {
        this.props.router.navigate('/');
    }

    render(): React.ReactNode {
        return (
            <div className="test" onClick={this.onNavigateHome}>test</div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(MyComponent));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, described here:
[Params from React Router with class components and typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73139861/params-from-react-router-with-class-components-and-typescript)

I created a new functional component, so I can use `useParams()`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

type Props = {
    children: JSX.Element
};

export const WithParams: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const params = useParams();
    return React.cloneElement(props.children, {...props.children.props, ...params });
};
```

and added it to my `Route.element`

```
<Route path="/Contacts/VerifyEmailAddress/:id" 
  element={
    <WithParams>
      <VerifyEmail />
    </WithParams>
  }>
</Route>
```

and added the parameters I need to the props of my child component.

```
export class VerifyEmailProps {
    public id?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote in typescript

```
import React from 'react'
import { Location, NavigateFunction, Params, useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

export function withRouter<P extends { router: RouterInfo }>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P>,
): React.ElementType<Omit<P, 'router'>> {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props: any) {
    const location = useLocation()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const params = useParams()
    return <Component {...props} router={{ location, navigate, params }} />
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp
}

interface RouterInfo {
  location: Location
  navigate: NavigateFunction
  params: Params
}

export interface WithRouter {
  router: RouterInfo
}
```

The `Omit<P, 'router'>` is there to remove router property from required props.

Your component:

```
interface Props extends WithRouter {
  ...component properties
}

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props)
    
    // access route:
    console.log(this.props.router.params.someEntityIdMaybe)
  }
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useParams` from react-router-dom, as follows:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function GenericShowPage() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <h1>{id}</h1>
  );
}

export default GenericShowPage
```