# PubSub not working within route components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, publish-subscribe

I was trying to pass data within route components. Since the `react-router-dom` remove props for class components in the latest version (v6), I just imported `pubsub.js` and tried to pass the data through the `Link` with an onclick event.

Here is the component waiting for publishing (showing part of codes).

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js';

export default class ProductDetails extends Component {
    state = {
        product: {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        PubSub.subscribe('product', (_, product) => {
            this.setState({product})
        })
    }
    render(){...}
}
```

Here is the component passing the data:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js';

export default class ProductHome extends Component {

    pubProduct = (product) => {
        return () => {
            PubSub.publish('product', product)
        }
    }

    ...
    render(){

    const product = {a: 1}


    <Link 
        to='/product/details' 
        onClick={this.pubProduct(product)}
    > Details </Link>

    ...
}
```

Both of them are route components. I also tried `publishSync` but still not working. After click the `Link`, the state in the `ProductDetails` component did not change.

If router doesn't support pubsub, how to pass data then? I know using hook apis in react-router-dom v6 could be the best way to handle this kind of problem. But for class components, is there a good way to pass any data within route components in v6?

Thanks!

Comment: Both of *what* are route components? Do you mean `ProductHome` and `ProductDetails` are rendered by a `Route`? How were you data in RRDv5, can you show us the older code that was (*presumably*) working? We can help convert or adapt it to RRDv6. Does this answer help with using RRDv6 with older class components? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69967902/8690857

Comment: @Drew Reese thanks for your response, this answer really helps!