# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') reactjs class based component

Tags: reactjs

I am using class based component with `reactjs` in my project and I want to access a single id from the database but I end up with this error

```
'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')'
```

Seems in function component using Hooks work with `useParams` so how does this work with class based component, I am using react "^17.0.2", Here are my sample codes.

```
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
    import PageTop from '../components/PageTop/PageTop'
    import TopNavigation from '../components/TopNavigation/TopNavigation'
    import Footer from '../components/Footer/Footer'
    import ProjectDetails from '../components/ProjectDetails/ProjectDetails'
    
     class ProjectDetailsPage extends Component {
    
          constructor({match}){
              super();
              this.state ={
                ProjectPassedID:match.params.projectID
              }
          }
          
    
        componentDidMount(){
         window.scroll(0,0)
       }
     render() {
      return (
       <Fragment>
        <TopNavigation title="Project Details"/>
         <PageTop pageTitle="Project Details"/>
         <ProjectDetails id={this.state.ProjectPassedID} />
         <Footer/>
       </Fragment>
      )
     }
    }
    
    export default ProjectDetailsPage




    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
    import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
    import { Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
    import projectDetails from '../../assets/image/pdetails.png'
    import {faCheckSquare} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
     class ProjectDetails extends Component {
    
                constructor(props){
                  super();
                  this.state ={
                    MyprojectId:props.id
                  }
                }
        
     render() {
      return (
       <Fragment>
                <Container className="mt-5">
                    <Row>
                         <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={12}>
                       <div className="about-thumb-wrap after-shape">
                        <img className="projectDetailsImg" src={projectDetails} alt="" />
                       </div>
                         </Col>
    
                         <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={12} className="mt-5">
                       <div className="project-details">
                        <h1 className="projectDetailsText">{this.state.MyprojectId}.</h1>
     </div>
                         </Col>
                    </Row>
        </Container>
       </Fragment>
      )
     }
    }
    
    export default ProjectDetails




    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
    import { Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
    import AboutPage from '../pages/AboutPage';
    import AllCoursePage from '../pages/AllCoursePage';
    import AllServicePage from '../pages/AllServicePage';
    import HomePage from '../pages/HomePage'
    import ContactPage from '../pages/ContactPage';
    import PortifolioPage from '../pages/PortifolioPage';
    import RefundPage from '../pages/RefundPage';
    import TermsPage from '../pages/TermsPage';
    import PrivacyPage from '../pages/PrivacyPage';
    import ProjectDetailsPage from '../pages/ProjectDetailsPage';
    import CourseDetailsPage from '../pages/CourseDetailsPage';
    
    class AppRouter extends Component {
     render() {
      return (
       <Fragment>
      
        <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/service" element={<AllServicePage/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/course" element={<AllCoursePage/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/portifolio" element={<PortifolioPage/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/about" element={<AboutPage/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/contact" element={<ContactPage/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/refund" element={<RefundPage/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/terms" element={<TermsPage/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/privacy" element={<PrivacyPage/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/projectdetails/:projectID" element={<ProjectDetailsPage/>}/>
             
          </Routes>
           
       </Fragment>
      )
     }
    }
    
    export default AppRouter
```

Comment: What is `match` that is passed into the constructor? Could you log that?

Comment: I creating this project while watching a tutorial and this is how was passed,

Comment: I wouldn't recommend blindly following a tutorial. Regardless, please log the contents of `match` using `console.log(match)` in the constructor and post the results.

Comment: nothing happening in a console when I log(match)

Comment: Where are you writing `console.log(match)`? Please put in in the constructor either before or after the line with `this.state`

Comment: I write it before the closing end of constructor curl bracket but nothing is displayed

Comment: This looks like the v6 issue around withRouter no longer being present. 
Class components are no longer able to easily acquire parameters as the 'withRouter' is no longer supported.

This is similar, if not identical, to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69967745/react-router-v6-access-a-url-parameter