# Uncaught TypeError: match is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

```
import books from '../books'


function BookScreen({ match }) {
    const book = books.find((b) => b._id === match.params.id)
    return (
        <div>
            {book}
        </div>
    )
}

export default BookScreen
```

I keep getting the error match is undefined. I saw a tutorial with similar code, but it seemed fine when put to the test. Any clue what might be the issue?

Comment: you should try the new way with `useParams()` to get url params

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `match` prop is undefined this could be from a few things.

## `react-router-dom` v5

If using RRDv5 if the `match` prop is undefined this means that `BookScreen` isn't receiving the [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) that are injected when a component is rendered on the `Route` component's `component` prop, or the `render` or `children` prop functions. Note that using `children` the route will match and render regardless, see [route render methods](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) for details.

Ensure that one of the following is implemented to access the `match` object:

1. Render `BookScreen` on the `component` prop of a `Route`

   ```
   <Route path="...." component={BookScreen} />
   ```
2. Render `BookScreen` on the `render` or `children` prop function of a `Route` and pass the route props through

   ```
   <Route path="...." render={props => <BookScreen {...props} />} />
   ```

   or

   ```
   <Route path="...." children={props => <BookScreen {...props} />} />
   ```
3. Decorate `BookScreen` with the [`withRouter`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component to have the route props injected

   ```
   import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

   function BookScreen = ({ match }) {
     const book = books.find((b) => b._id === match.params.id)
     return (
       <div>
         {book}
       </div>
     );
   };

   export default withRouter(BookScreen);
   ```
4. Since `BookScreen` is a React function component, import and use the [`useParams`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) hook to access the route match params

   ```
   import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

   ...

   function BookScreen() {
     const { id } = useParams();
     const book = books.find((b) => b._id === id)
     return (
       <div>
         {book}
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

## `react-router-dom` v6

If using RRDv6 then there is no `match` prop. Gone are the route props. Here only the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams) and other hooks exist, so use them.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

function BookScreen() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const book = books.find((b) => b._id === id)
  return (
    <div>
      {book}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you've other class components and you're using RRDv6 and you don't want to convert them to function components, then you'll need to create a custom `withRouter` component. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69967902/8690857) with details.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you rendered BookScreen component before match is initialized. This is why match is undefined when BookScreen rendered. Render it conditionally like below.

```
return (
  ... other components
 {match && <BookScreen match={match}/>}

)
```

Also, I leave useful site which tells you some good ways to do that. :D

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/7-ways-to-implement-conditional-rendering-in-react-applications

I hope you find an answer :D