# React router v5 to v6 Migration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router-dom

I'm learning to react and trying to migrate an app from the react-router v5 to v6. I have an issue with the routing and need to fix that. The UI looks like below:

[image]

If I click the title say `Airplane` or the `New Movie` button, it provides me the blank page now with the correct URL. Practically, the code should hit the route `<Route path="/movies/:id" element={<MovieForm/>}/>` and take me to the `MovieForm` page.

The code for the `App.js` is below (I migrated to v6 with the Routes and element tag)

```
function App() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <NavBar/>
            <main className="container">
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterForm/>}/>
                    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginForm/>}/>
                    <Route path="/movies/:id" element={<MovieForm/>}/>
                    <Route path="/movies" element={<Movies/>}/>
                    <Route path="/customers" component={<Customers/>}/>
                    <Route path="/rentals" component={<Rentals/>}/>
                    <Route path="/not-found" component={<NotFound/>}/>

                    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/movies" />} />
                    <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate replace to="/not-found" />} />
                </Routes>
            </main>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

The `MovieForm` code is below:

```
class MovieForm extends Form {

    state = {
        data: {
            title: "",
            genreId: "",
            numberInStock: "",
            dailyRentalRate: ""
        },
        genres: [],
        errors: {}
    };

    schema = {
        _id: Joi.string(),
        title: Joi.string()
            .required()
            .label("Title"),
        genreId: Joi.string()
            .required()
            .label("Genre"),
        numberInStock: Joi.number()
            .required()
            .min(0)
            .max(100)
            .label("Number in Stock"),
        dailyRentalRate: Joi.number()
            .required()
            .min(0)
            .max(10)
            .label("Daily Rental Rate")
    };




    componentDidMount() {
        const genres = getGenres();
        this.setState({ genres });

        const movieId = this.props.match.params.id;
        if (movieId === "new") return;

        const movie = getMovie(movieId);
        if (!movie) return this.props.history.replace("/not-found");

        this.setState({ data: this.mapToViewModel(movie) });
    }

    mapToViewModel(movie) {
        return {
            _id: movie._id,
            title: movie.title,
            genreId: movie.genre._id,
            numberInStock: movie.numberInStock,
            dailyRentalRate: movie.dailyRentalRate
        };
    }


    doSubmit = () => {
        saveMovie(this.state.data);

        this.props.history.push("/movies");
    };



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Movie Form</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    {this.renderInput("title", "Title")}
                    {this.renderSelect("genreId", "Genre", this.state.genres)}
                    {this.renderInput("numberInStock", "Number in Stock", "number")}
                    {this.renderInput("dailyRentalRate", "Rate")}
                    {this.renderButton("Save")}
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MovieForm;
```

The UI page (the image provided above) is `movies.js` and the code is below:

```
class Movies extends Component {
    state = {
        movies: [],
        genres: [],
        pageSize: 4,
        currentPage: 1,
        sortColumn: { path: 'title', order: 'asc' },
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const genres = [{ name: 'All Genres', _id: '' }, ...getGenres()];
        this.setState({ movies: getMovies(), genres: genres });
    }

    handleDelete = (movie) => {
        console.log('Deleting the movie named => ' + movie.title);

        const moviesAfterDelete = this.state.movies.filter(
            (m) => m._id !== movie._id
        );
        this.setState({ movies: moviesAfterDelete });
    };

    handleLike = (movie) => {
        const movies = [...this.state.movies];
        const index = movies.indexOf(movie);

        movies[index] = { ...movies[index] };
        movies[index].liked = !movies[index].liked;

        this.setState({ movies });
    };

    handlePageChange = (page) => {
        this.setState({ currentPage: page });
    };

    handleGenreSelect = (genre) => {
        this.setState({ selectedGenre: genre, currentPage: 1 });
    };

    handleSort = (sortColumn) => {

        this.setState({ sortColumn});
    };

    handleSearch = (query) =>{
        this.setState({
            searchQuery: query,
            selectedGenre: null,
            currentPage: 1,
        });
    };

    getPageData = ()=>{
        const {
            pageSize,
            currentPage,
            sortColumn,
            selectedGenre,
            searchQuery,
            movies: allMovies,
        } = this.state;


        let filtered = allMovies;
        if (searchQuery)
            filtered = allMovies.filter((m) =>
                m.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
            );
        else if (selectedGenre && selectedGenre._id)
            filtered = allMovies.filter(
                (m) => m.genre._id === selectedGenre._id
            );


        const sorted = _.orderBy(
            filtered,
            [sortColumn.path],
            [sortColumn.order]
        );

        const movies = paginate(sorted, currentPage, pageSize);

        return {totalCount: filtered.length, data: movies};

    };

    render() {
        const { length: count } = this.state.movies;
        const {
            pageSize,
            currentPage,
            sortColumn,
            searchQuery
        } = this.state;

        if (count === 0) return <p>There are no movies in the database!</p>;

        const {totalCount, data: movies} = this.getPageData();

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-3">
                    <ListGroup
                        items={this.state.genres}
                        selectedItem={this.state.selectedGenre}
                        onItemSelect={this.handleGenreSelect}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="col">

                    <Link
                        to="/movies/new"
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
                    >
                        New Movie
                    </Link>
                    <p>Showing {totalCount} movies in the database.</p>

                    <SearchBox
                        value={searchQuery}
                        onChange={this.handleSearch}
                    />

                    <MoviesTable
                        movies={movies}
                        onLike={this.handleLike}
                        sortColumn={sortColumn}
                        onDelete={this.handleDelete}
                        onSort={this.handleSort}
                    />
                    <Pagination
                        itemsCount={totalCount}
                        pageSize={pageSize}
                        currentPage={currentPage}
                        onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Movies;
```

If you look closely in the class above, the New Movie button is there -

```
                    <Link
                        to="/movies/new"
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
                    >
                        New Movie
                    </Link>
```

When I click the `Airplane` and `New Movie` button, I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
    at MovieForm.componentDidMount (movieForm.js:49:1)
```

Now, how do I make sure that when I click the links RED colored in the image, I get the correct page than the blank page and the route `<Route path="/movies/:id" element={<MovieForm/>}/>` is working correctly in the react-router v6?

Thanks.

Comment: I see no issue with the routes or the link to `"/movies/new"`. I noticed that `MovieForm` was missing a declaration for `handleSubmit` though. Is this full and complete, reproducible code? Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: This code was running in the v5 and I migrate to the v6. Then, when I click the links, I received the blank pages. I'm new to reactjs programming and learning, so need this to be fixed.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Are you rendering a router higher in the ReactTree than `App` component?

Comment: Yes, there is an error when I click the `Airplane` and the `New Movie` button: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
    at MovieForm.componentDidMount (movieForm.js:49:1)
`

Comment: I believe this is the line `const movieId = this.props.match.params.id;` that gave the error in the `Movieform`

Comment: Right, I think this is your issue then. What are your thoughts on converting these class components to function components that need to access the old RRDv5 route props? Would you prefer to keep these as class components? Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69967902/8690857) help you? You basically need to either convert to function component to use the React hooks, or create a custom `withRouter` HOC to do that and pass them as props.

Comment: I prefer to keep it as a class component and need a working solution for that. This code works for the v5, how do I run it for v6?