# Unsure how to go about replicating React Component lifecycle methods through useEffect() where componentDidMount calls a function within a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I want to make it so that my App component renders something depending on the specific route location the app is in. The problem is that to determine the location, I would need for my App component to be a functional component as useLocation requires a component that can use hooks. My problem comes in where in my original App component, it is a class component that has a component did mount that looks like this:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")){
      this.props.autoLogin();
    }
    this.makeButtons("button");
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollCloseHamburger);
  }
```

Which calls makeButtons which looks like this:

```
makeButtons = (origin) => {//Makes the button list depending on the componenents present in the componenet list

if (origin === "button"){
  for (let i = 1; i < this.state.componentList.length + 1; i++){
    this.setState((prevstate) => ({buttonList: prevstate.buttonList.concat(<button key={i-1} onClick={() => this.handleClick((i-1).toString())}>Script {i}</button>)}));
  } 
}
else if (origin === "pages"){
  
  for (let i = 1; i < this.state.page_counts[this.props.texts.currentScript] + 1; i++){
    this.setState((prevstate) => ({pageList: prevstate.pageList.concat(<button key={i-1} onClick={() => this.handlePageButtonClick(i)}>Page {i}</button>)}))
  }
}
```

}

This then calls the functions handleClick() and handlePageButtonClick().

When I tried to make it into a functional component, I used useEffect() to replicate componentDidMount, but I ran into the problem where makeButtons() wasn't defined. I tried to remedy this by doing

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")){
      props.autoLogin();
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollCloseHamburger);
  }, [])

  const makeButtons = useCallback((origin) => {
      if (origin === "button"){
         for (let i = 1; i < this.state.componentList.length + 1; i++){
           this.setState((prevstate) => ({buttonList: prevstate.buttonList.concat(<button key={i-1} onClick={() => this.handleClick((i-1).toString())}>Script {i}</button>)}));
         } 
      }
      else if (origin === "pages"){
         for (let i = 1; i < this.state.page_counts[this.props.texts.currentScript] + 1; i++){
    this.setState((prevstate) => ({pageList: prevstate.pageList.concat(<button key={i-1} onClick={() => this.handlePageButtonClick(i)}>Page {i}</button>)}))
       }
      }
  }
```

The problem then was that handleClick and handlePageButtonClick were not defined.

Ultimately, my question is if there is any way to actually make this into a functional component where I would be able to run makeButtons("button") on and only on the rendering of the component.

If not, how would I go about reading the location if it's not a functional component?

Comment: What version of `react-router` or `react-router-dom` is installed? From the project's directory you can check by running `npm list react-router react-router-dom`.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm using react-router-dom@6.3.0

Comment: Does my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69967902/8690857) help explain creating a custom `withRouter` HOC to use for your class component and RRDv6? You'd use the `useLocation` hook instead of (*or in addition to*) the `useParams` hook in the code example.

Comment: Why are you even putting your buttons in state, to start with? This makes no sense. That logic should go inside the `render` logic.

Comment: It looks like that might be the way to go about it but I'm just failing to understand a few minor points.
1) Would I put App instead of WrappedComponent? Also would I then change my index.js to have withRouter instead of App? 
2) What is Post? You say in your answer export default withRouter(Post); which is a syntax I haven't seen before. 
I'm somewhat new to React Router so I don't fully understand how to implement these.

Comment: The thing is I change the buttons at various points. I didn't put my whole component here but when it changes the way it does it would only make sense to keep it in state.

Comment: @Bergi meaning I call make buttons many times

Comment: @zichyboy You mean you call `makeButtons` every time you change `state.componentList.length`, right?

Comment: @DrewReese I looked at what you gave me again and I realize now exactly what everything does, this was the solution! Thank you!

Comment: I see... sorry I missed what looks to be a response to me yesterday. Yeah, looks like you might've just been missing some base level of knowledge around Higher Order Components and how they "decorate" regular React components.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the following:

- If you are using functional components, work with the 'useState' hook to manage the state. You can later reference the destructured variables and methods freely as long as they are within the scope of the component, without using 'this'.

```
const [scripts, setScripts] = useState();

// Inside render:
<h1> {scripts.length} </h1>
// ...
<button onClick={() => setScripts([])}> Erase Scripts </button>
```

- Same concept with methods you create:

```
const handleScriptButtonClick = () => {};

// Inside render:
<button onClick={handleScriptButtonClick}> Script </button>
```

- Try to avoid using indices as keys in arrays if you can. Ideally find some other unique identifier.
- Try to avoid using the state to store a big list of elements or components. It's preferable to store the data associated with the buttons you want to create and then build them inside the render method. Something like this:

```
render() {
// ...
<section>
      { scripts.map((script, i) => 
        <button key={script.id} onClick={() => handleScriptButtonClick(script)}>
          Script {i}
        </button>
      )}
 </section>
}
```

Comment: I am trying to make it into a functional component. I know about useState and will definitely be using it to replace my current state setup, but the problem is useEffect not meeting my qualifications.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was thanks to Drew Reese.

The solution was that I used [this post by Drew Reese][1] to accomplish it. I made a higher order function, appWrapper

```js
const appWrapper = (WrappedComponent) => props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  
  return (
    <WrappedComponent {...props}
    location={location} />
  )
}
```

And simply made my export default statement this:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(appWrapper(App));
```

Note I'm using redux as well so that's what all the connect and everything is.

Thank you again Drew for all of your help!
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69967902/8690857