# Is using parts of the URL instead of props for generated class component pages (e.g. specific product page) a good React practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new to React, and I'm writing a web store front-end using react router dom to generate pages for the specific product. I split the url for the product page to get product ID and pass that ID as a prop to product class components (like product images, price, qunaitiy, description...), the components then make separate apollo queries for the information they need to properly render. The routes part of the code looks like this:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
    <Route exact path="/:productCategory" element={<CategoryComponent />} />
    <Route exact path="/:productCategory/:productID" element={<ProductPageComponent />} />
</Routes>
```

I have some doubts about using javascript to split the url and get the product ID from it - it works fine, but somehow feels hacky - is there a better way? I cannot use useParams or any hooks at all - I must use class components for this.

Comment: It *is* hackish. Why are you splitting the URL when you can just use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params) hook to access the route path params?

Comment: I am limited to class components and can't use hooks. Will update my question to include that detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question then? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69967902/8690857 You are using `react-router-dom@6` so the options you have are to use the React hooks by either converting the class components to function components, create a custom `withRouter` HOC, or hack the URL like you already are. The answer I linked covers creating the HOC, it's the most straight-forward method of accessing the route params for a class component.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good practice because those components are dynamic when receiving params.

[read more](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params)

Comment: I am limited to class components and can't use hooks. Will update my question to include that detail.