# uncaught typeerror props.match is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Hi I am trying to get `params.id` from my url but some how it is returning `props.match` is undefined.
Data.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Data extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
    this.state = { user: [] };

    console.log('username', props.match.params.id);

  const FetchUsers = async (user) => {
    const API_Call = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${user}`)
    const data = await API_Call.json();
    return { data }
  }

  FetchUsers(props.match.params.id)
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState({ user: res.data.items })
    })
}
```

App.js

```
<Nav/>          
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<Main />} />
      <Route exact path='/DataId/:id' element={<DataId />} />
      <Route exact path='/Data/:id' element={<Data />} />
      <Route exact path='/Specific/:login' element={<Specific />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
```

I tried using `useParams()` but because it is a class I cant get it to work.
I tried using `this.props.match` also returning undefined error.

P/S thank you for helping me i found the same answer as suggested.
[React-router-v6 access a url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69967745/react-router-v6-access-a-url-parameter)

Comment: what you want to obtain from use params

Comment: I will need the params id to filter out the user id for display.
So if params.id is genebent it will display every user with the username genebent
useParams() was one of the solution i found but later realized it cannot work for class component.
But somehow props.match.params.id is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import * as qs from "query-string";
constructor(props){ 
super(props);
const params = qs.parse(window.location.search);
console.log(params.id);
}
```

Comment: Hi this method works for me but it is showing undefined instead

Comment: OP wants route path params, not URL queryString params. This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      product: {},
      loading: true,
      
    };
  }

componentDidMount(){
        const currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
        const id = currentUrl.replace("/", "");
        
        getProductDetail(id).then((response)=>{
          this.setState({product:response.data.product,loading:false})
        })
        
      }

This is how i achive the same thing
```

Comment: It is returning an error class constructor have to be invoked with new
`

componentDidMount(){
    const currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
    const id = currentUrl.replace("/", "");
    
    Data(id).then((response)=>{
      this.setState({product:response.data.product,loading:false})
    })
    
  }
`

Comment: updated how to invoke constructor

Comment: Somehow Data is still showing constructor have to be invoked with new

Comment: show error from console

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'