# how to fetch url that contains an array dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, fetch

im having trouble figuring out how to fetch a url that contains an array in react

the parent component fetches data that gets sent to two components.

```
export default class ParentComponent extends Component<AuthProps, ChannelState> {
constructor(props: AuthProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        ...
        }
    }
    getChannel = () => {
        console.log("get channel called")
        fetch(`${APIURL}/channel/mine`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: new Headers({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `${this.props.sessionToken}`
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            this.setState({
                channel: data
            })
            console.log(this.state.channel, "channel called")
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

the state gets sent to two child components. childcomponent1 is a route that uses channelId in the fetch method. childcomponent2 displays a dynamic link to component1 using channelId as a key

```
export default class ChildComponent1 extends Component<AuthProps, ChannelEntryState> {
constructor(props: AuthProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        ...
    }
}
getChannelEntry = () => {
    console.log("get channel entry called")
    console.log(this.props.channel.length)
    fetch(`${APIURL}/channel/${this.props.channel[1].channelId}/channelentry`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `${this.props.sessionToken}`
        })
    })

    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({
            channelEntry: data.messages
        })
        console.log(this.state.channelEntry, "channel entry called")
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

const ChildComponent2 = (props: AuthProps) => {
return(
      <Row>
        {props.channel.map((cprops: ChannelType) => {
            return(
              <>
               <Col>
                <div>
                 <ul className="sidebar-list list-unstyled" key={cprops.channelId}>
                  <li><Link to={`/channelEntry/${cprops.channelId}`}><Button onClick={() => {console.log('button clicked')}}>{cprops.name}</Button></Link></li>
                 </ul>
                </div>
               </Col>
              </>
             )
           })}
```

Ive looked into useParams but i believe its only possible in a functional component. I believe i shouldnt use functional components when states can change. How can i fetch the url in component1 dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean "fetch a url that contains an array in react"? Are you trying to do n fetches for each props.channel element that is sent to Child1?

Comment: yeah i didnt explain it well sorry. there will be multiple links in component2 that i create. each one is mapped by its channelId. when i click a link getChannelEntry is called but i dont know how to link that channelId between child1 and child2. you can see i have a placeholder for the fetch that calls the second array in channel i.e. channel[1]

Answer (score 0):

Concerning params you can access them in a react class component using `this.props.match.params`.

And concerning the `useParams`, two things

- yes, anything with a `use` in front of a name should be a **hook** and can only be used in functional components.
- no, functional components, since React v17, can have their own states, using the `useState` hook.

just keep in mind that the you can have **multiple states** in functional components so you should use a state for **each** controlled part.

Answer (score 0):

for people using react typescript class components look into this link
[React-router-v6 access a url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69967745/react-router-v6-access-a-url-parameter)

Comment: I see you are new to stack overflow. Welcome. Thank you for your contribution. Given this is a QA site, your answer could help users better if it was in the form of an answer vs. a recommendation.  Working code is always a plus.

Comment: I see you are new to stack overflow. Welcome. Thank you for your contribution. Given this is a QA site, your answer could help users better if it was in the form of an answer vs. a recommendation. Working code is always a plus.